# Create file and check it in debug mode in Android Studio

Tags: android, file, android-studio, android-debug

I am using android studio and I debug using my connected device which is my phone. 
I was wandering after creating a file, how can I physically see that file. I mean not programmatically.

Here is my code to copy an xml file to my internal memory. it seems it gets copied but I can't see and confirm. 
Is there anyway in android studio to check that  ?

```
File file = new File("server.xml");
    try {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.server);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while((len=inputStream.read(buf))>0) {
            fileOutputStream.write(buf,0,len);
        }

        fileOutputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
adb shell run-as your.package.name
cat files/server.xml
```